# Bootstrap 4 , is there any way to force date input to accept only 4 digit year

Tags: angular, input, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap 4 with angular 2, i need something like `year` input, and `month` input, for this need is it possible to force date input to accept year, and then another date input to accept only month ? Or any other solution way.

Comment: if you simply want to get date in any formate you can simply make use of available datepicker plugin...

Comment: @RohitS at main i want to provide an option for user to set a period not a date. Ok it is now clear i can use a number input instead

Comment: great that's fine..